# Remove tags in Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I would like to remove the html tag, but preserve the text in between the tags and maintain it in the list. This is my following code:

```
comment_list = comment_container.findAll("div", {"class" : "comment-date"})
print(comment_list)
```

Output is:

```
[<div class="comment-date">2018-9-11 03:58</div>, 
 <div class="comment-date">2018-4-4 17:10</div>, 
 <div class="comment-date">2018-4-26 01:06</div>, 
 <div class="comment-date">2018-7-19 13:48</div>, 
 <div class="comment-date">2018-4-12 11:39</div>, 
 <div class="comment-date">2019-3-14 21:12</div>, 
 <div class="comment-date">2019-3-4 15:43</div>, 
 <div class="comment-date">2019-3-12 13:20</div>, 
 <div class="comment-date">2019-3-10 22:32</div>, 
 <div class="comment-date">2019-3-8 15:22</div>]
```

Desired Output:

```
[2018-9-11 03:58, 2018-4-4 17:10, 2018-4-26 01:06, 
2018-7-19 13:48, 2018-4-12 11:39, 2019-3-14 21:12, 
2019-3-4 15:43, 2019-3-12 13:20, 2019-3-10 22:32, 2019-3-8 15:22]
```

I am able to extract the text individually by using a for loop.

```
for commentDate in comment_list:
    comments = commentDate.text
    print(comments)
```

I would like to use the dates for comparison (finding the earliest date), hence i feel that saving the dates into a list will be most manageable.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your list of `div` elements to list of dates using list comprehension like this to get desired output:

```
comment_list = comment_container.findAll("div", {"class" : "comment-date"})
comment_dates = [comment.text for comment in comment_list]
print(comment_dates)
```

Comment: @glhe13, Please accept the answer to close the question if your problem is solved. Or you can share any issues you faced.